# function that takes dictionary called employees (see below), returns 3 lists

Tags: python

```
employees = {
    'Tom': {
        'Age': 34,
        'Job': 'teller'
    },
    'Sam': {
        'Age': 24,
        'Job': 'HR'
    },
    'Hellen': {
        'Age': 37,
        'Job': 'PR'
    },
    'Owen': {
        'Age': 27,
        'Job': 'SM'
    },
    'David': {
        'Age': 34,
        'Job': 'Associate'
    },
    'Ashley': {
        'Age': 23,
        'Job': 'Reception'
    }
}
    
Reception = []
PR = []
SM = []
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a single loop as well to achieve this -

```
employees = { 'Tom': { 'Age': 34, 'Job': 'teller' }, 
             'Sam': { 'Age': 24, 'Job': 'HR' }, 
             'Hellen': { 'Age': 37, 'Job': 'PR' }, 
             'Owen': { 'Age': 27, 'Job': 'SM' }, 
             'David': { 'Age': 34, 'Job': 'Associate' }, 
             'Ashley': { 'Age': 23, 'Job': 'Reception' } }

>>> for key in employees:
    if employees[key]['Job'] == 'Reception': Reception += [key]
    elif employees[key]['Job'] == 'PR': PR += [key]
    elif employees[key]['Job'] == 'SM': SM += [key]
... 
>>> 
>>> Reception
['Ashley']
>>> Reception,SM,PR
(['Ashley'], ['Owen'], ['Hellen'])
>>>
```